# Obtaining phone type in string, when type is custom

Tags: android, android-contacts

I obtained contact list from phone with names, phone numbers and phone types. Phone types may be 1 (home), 2 (mobile), etc... And when phone type is custom (for example, "CustomType"), value of phone type returns 0. So, how can i obtain string "CustomType", when phone type is 0 ?

Comment: Why you do not use the logic similar to `if(phoneValue == 0) { phoneType = "CustomType"; }`?

Comment: but if type is 0, string may be "CutomType" or "MyType" or "AnotherType" etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this code will be useful:

```
String contactType = "";
final int labelType = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
if(labelType == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM)
{
    contactType = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL));
}
else
{
     //Easy case
}
```

**cur** is your cursor that execute the query `....getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI...`